# How to solve $Y\left( x\right) A\left( x\right) +Y^{\prime }\left( x\right) =B\left( x\right) $ in non-commutative Banach algebras?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, banach-algebras

I'm trying to solve $Y\left( x\right) A\left( x\right) +Y^{\prime }\left(
x\right) =B\left( x\right) $ in the Banach algebra of bounded operators.
Multiplying both sides by $\exp \left( \int^{x}A\left( t\right) dt\right) $
doesn't have the same consequence as in commutative Banach algebras. So, what
can we do to solve this differential equation ?

Thank you !